# Condition based variable in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT. Acutally I want to assign value to a variable `color` based on condition

```
<xsl:for-each select="report/task">
    <xsl:variable name="color" select="@status"/>
    ...
</xsl:for-each>
```

I want to assign different colors **(red, yellow, green)** based on status **(Pending, Progress, Completed)**.

Comment: Why down vote? I am new to this XSLT. If anything wrong, guide me to correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution:

```
<xsl:for-each select="report/task">
    <xsl:variable name="color">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@status = 'Pending'">red</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="@status = 'Progress'">yellow</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="@status = 'Completed'">green</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>white</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
</xsl:for-each>
```

It is working...